# How to send JsonResult from a Controller to a View and access it using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my first MVC project. I am building a Bing Map application (that loads multiple pushpins on the map).

Here's my Index ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Index(string Id)
{

    // Here is the code to populate the DataSet using Id parameter

    DataTable dtReport = ds.Tables[0];
    List<MapPoint> points = new List<MapPoint>();
    int index = 1;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        points.Add(GetPointInfo(r, false));
        index++;
    }

    //return the list as JSON
    return Json(points, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My problem is, when I go to the Index view, all I see is the **Json formatted data** and the map disappears. I would assume this happens because I am returning JsonResult in the Index ActionResult.

Is there any way I can retain the map on the View and still be able to pass JsonResult to the Index view and access it using jQuery?

Comment: Are you using jQuery for sending an ajax request to the server and consuming the response using javascript? Something like [this](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/739/ajax-aspnet-mvc-3). If so, could you post the javascript in the client side?

Comment: Currently I use another method called GetLocations in the controller and using somthing like this: $.getJSON("/GetLocations/", stripNull({ Id: '090' }), function (data) { code here }); but my problem with this is I need to access URL parameter. So, I want to achieve everything using the Index view if possible.

Comment: Pass the json result in `view data` and you can use the `view data result` in javascript. make sure your action returns view and not json.

Answer (score 2):

Just return the view,and serialize the data to json,then pass the json data to the view.
Operate the json data with javascript in the page.

Comment: Fixed it last night @shimrom. I used ViewBag to pass JSON data. Thanks.