# How to asynchronously call multiple stored procs(model) and assign the result set from controller to a variable in view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I use edmx in the model.

Now in the controller I understand that Index will be called initially.

What if i want to fetch multiple result sets on pageload?? how can i call multiple stored procs and assign results from them to variables in the view??

Controller code

```
public ActionResult ViewQuery() {

  DBController dBController = new DBController();
  ViewBag.JsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dBController.xxxxx());
  return View();
  }
```

Now in the view i have the below line, which fetches value from the controller if the code is placed in Index()

```
 var resultset=@(Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonData))
```

**If I have the code that is currently in `ViewQuery()` inside `Index()` function, then it is working fine, but if i have it in `ViewQuery` it is not working** !! I am not getting the `ViewBag.JsonData`  Please help

Comment: any answers or comments before closing or downvoting?

Comment: I did not downvote but probably this is the reason: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: You're missing the point of MVC. Shoving business logic into your views is sending you down a deep dark path of duplicate code and heaps of time spent fixing bugs.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I am new to mvc. in 3-tier arch  I used to call web-methods from the aspx page which will fetch me results from db. How am i supposed to do that in mvc ?? I want to asynchronously fetch multiple data and populate them in the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Improve perceived performance of ASP.NET MVC websites with asynchronous partial views](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/11/13/improve-perceived-performance-of-asp-net-mvc-websites-with-async-partialviews/)
 This post tell you how to use jquery and mvc parital views to load page asynchronously.

If you don't want to use this way, please check this question [How to send JsonResult from a Controller to a View and access it using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088256/how-to-send-jsonresult-from-a-controller-to-a-view-and-access-it-using-jquery/18095315#18095315)

Updated(Change your code):

```
public ActionResult ViewQuery() 
{       
    DBController dBController = new DBController();     
    ViewBag.JsonData= dBController.GetXXX(); 
    return Json(dBController.usp_CIOChallenge_Admin_view_query(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in your view you can make ajax call to the controller to fetch results

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/ViewQuery",
    responseType:"json",
    success: successfn,
    error:errorfn
});
function successfn(result) {

};
```

Comment: I am not able to get the data from controller to view :( 
I am returning a viewbag from controller but it throws error

Comment: @vignesh if you choose the second way,you should return 'View()' instead of 'Json()' in your action. Show me the code, if you still cannot fix it.

Comment: ya i have edited the question you can check that
I will try view() now

Comment: I changed the Json to view still the same error, not sure of the problem

Comment: @vignesh I have updated the answer,check it

Comment: I get the data after serializing it and use @Html.Raw in the view :)

Comment: I have only one problem left !!
If i have this in index its working but how to have it in other actionresult and call them??

Comment: @vignesh you can provide an ajax api to server the data or create a partial view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43761/discussion-between-vignesh-and-shimron)

Answer (score 2):

Need add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in Json(...)

```
   public ActionResult ViewQuery() 
   {   
       DBController dBController = new DBController();
       var result = Json(dBController.usp_xxxxxxx());
       return Json(dBController.usp_xxxxxxx(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Neolit
In the view I am not able to manipulate the result set
I tried 
var result = JSON.parse( @Html.Action("ViewQuery"));

Comment: Sorry @neolit I am going to delete the question as it got negative votes !!